how to convert float nan to int in python
I have the following sentence:
record["SupplierID"] = (
    int(record["SupplierID"])
    if record["SupplierID"] not in ["", "nan", np.nan, None, float(np.nan)]
    else None
)

But I'm getting this error: cannot convert float NaN to integer. I tried to catch the case but none of the cases is in the condition catches the case.
How can I catch the float(nan) case to avoid it?

Use np.isnan to check for NaN values
